# IsPostBack does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms, ispostback

So basically I need a if(!IsPostBack) check in my windows form c# application because after grabbing a value from a textbox once it is no longer grabbing that value and instead giving null. However I am getting the error. The error:

```
The name IsPostBack does not exist in the current context
```

I have:

```
using System.Web.UI;
```

So i'm not sure why this is happening. Any insight or solutions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
        if(!IsPostBack)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Text: " + textBox2.Text);
            MakeSureFieldIsFilledIn errormessagefieldempty = new MakeSureFieldIsFilledIn();
            errormessagefieldempty.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: IsPostBack is a WebForms concept, not WinForms. In a desktop environment, you never issue a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it sounds like you're trying to do, you should move this snippet to your event handler.

Comment: I'd argue for using the [ErrorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than waiting to "Submit" the data

Comment: That would work too. I was just suggesting the closest option in the WinForms paradigm.